# Converting IIF statement to Decode oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

How do I convert the following IIF statement to oracle decode statement :

```
IIF(lkp_LAST_NAME1 = 'Unknown', lkp_LAST_NAME1,
IIF(lkp_FIRST_NAME1 =' ' OR lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1 = ' ',lkp_LAST_NAME1,
IIF(ISNULL(lkp_LAST_NAME1), lkp_FIRST_NAME1 || ' ' || lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1,
IIF((ISNULL(lkp_FIRST_NAME1) AND ISNULL(lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1)), lkp_LAST_NAME1,
lkp_LAST_NAME1 || ', ' || lkp_FIRST_NAME1 || ' ' || lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1))))
```

Comment: `decode` does not allow conditions inside, but "loops" over the list of provided values and exits on the first match (as `case <expr> wnen <value1> then <out1> ... end` do). So you need to rewrite it to [searched](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm#i1033392) `case` expression

Comment: @astentx So do you mean to say it can be written in case when statement rather than decode right?

Comment: Yes. The only handy decode application is mapping of list of values, which also allows nulls processing (I mean `decode(val, null, something, val1, res1)` works as written, but `case` [doesn't process null](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3064a12fc86637f3862a758423ac0bac) in enumeration. All the other conditional processing is for `case`. This is because Oracle have no Boolean type to use for enumeration

Answer (score 0):

CASE should take care of it

```
case 
  when  lkp_LAST_NAME1 = 'Unknown' then   lkp_LAST_NAME1
  else 
    case when lkp_FIRST_NAME1 =' ' OR lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1 = ' ' then lkp_LAST_NAME1
    else 
      case when lkp_LAST_NAME1 is null then lkp_FIRST_NAME1 || ' ' || lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1
      else
        case when lkp_FIRST_NAME1 is null and lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1 is null then lkp_LAST_NAME1
        else lkp_LAST_NAME1 || ', ' || lkp_FIRST_NAME1 || ' ' || lkp_MIDDLE_NAME1
        end
      end
    end
  end
```